# Why do sqlite3 DB_API qmark and named style not work in "select where" queries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-db-api

Assuming I have a database with table `users` with a row:

`ID = 0, name = 'myName'`

I can get the ID value (assuming I'm connected) by using either:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT ID FROM users WHERE %s = %s""" % ('name', 'myName'))
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

or

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT ID FROM users WHERE {} = {}""".format('name', 'myName'))
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

which both work perfectly fine but are bad practice according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

The documentation suggest using either qmark or named style for queries with variable input. The problem arises when using the suggested styles in a `SELECT * FROM myDatabase WHERE ? = ?` query.

qmark style:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT ID FROM users WHERE ? = ?""", ('name', 'myName'))
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

named style

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT ID FROM users WHERE :column = :cell""", {'column': 'name', 'cell':'myName'})
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

Using either of the latter styles results in a `None` returned. When using the qmark or named style in the context of `INSERT` such as used in the example in the documentation it does work as expected.

(To clarify, with the qmark style, adding parentheses to each `?` or the entire `? = ?` does not change the outcome. Using parentheses with each `?` and using an additional argument causes `execute()` to malfunction due to too many arguments given.)

What causes this behaviour? Is it possible to use qmark or named style in a `SELECT...WHERE ? = ?` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter substitution is for *values*, not *identifiers* (the names of columns and tables etc).  RDBMS have different rules for quoting values and [identifiers](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).  Using the parameter substitution placeholder for identifiers leads to the identifier being incorrectly quoted, for example

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ? = ?', ('col1', 42))
```

ends up as

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 'col1' = 42
```

note the single quotes around col1, which cause it to evaluated as a string, not a column name.

If you want to have dynamic identifiers as well as values in your query then use string formatting for the identifiers and parameter substitution for the values.  For example, using double quotes for the identifier

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE "{}" = ?'.format('col1'), (42,))
```

Here's an example of string formatting resulting in an error

```py
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('create table tbl (col1 date)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f56abcf1ce0>
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('INSERT INTO tbl (col1) VALUES(?)', ('2021-05-01',))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f56abc8f030>
>>> cur.execute('INSERT INTO tbl (col1) VALUES(%s)' % '2021-05-01')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f56abc8f030>
>>> conn.commit()
>>> cur.execute('SELECT col1 FROM tbl WHERE %s = %s' % ('col1', '2021-05-01'))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f56abc8f030>
>>> for row in cur:print(row)
... 
(2015,)
```

When string formatting is used in the `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements, the date is evaluated as an arithmetic expression, resulting in the wrong value being stored and retrieved.  Errors like this are annoying, but using string formatting can also leave your application to SQL injection attacks, which could have more serious consequences.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Could you name an injection-proof method utilizing dynamic identifiers for further study?

Comment: I'm not aware of one for sqlite specifically.  Generally identifier quoting is easier than value quoting, because all identifier names can be quoted in the same way, whereas how a value is quoted depends on the type.  So if you want to create the occasional dynamic identifier it's probably enough to wrap your formatting placeholder in double quotes (note the characters used to quote identifiers may vary by RDBMS).  For a more sophisticated system, you might walk the abstract syntax tree of the SQL statement and find things to quote (I think SQLAlchemy's SQL compiler  does something like this).

Comment: You can get a list of columns from [cursor,description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.description) once the query has executed.

Comment: You might want to take look at the results of a Google search like "python sqlite dynamic queries site:stackoverflow.com" - the results should show you a number of approaches to building dynamic queries, with some discussion of the pros and cons.  Also, understand that your question shouldn't really shift focus once it has started receiving answers - it may be better to refine and ask a new question at that point.  But enjoy playing with query building, it's fun :-)