# Psycopg2 Postgres issue with inserting text with single quote

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am having trouble inserting text with single quotes into Postgres DB using psycogp2. This is the error I get whenever it encounters text with single quotes.

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "dept of health (department), in consul" does not exist
```

When I removed the single quotes in the text.. the record was inserted without any issue.

Here's my query:

```
query = "INSERT INTO %s VALUES %s ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET %s;" % (name, tuple(row), ', '
                                                                                            ''.join(update_string))
```

I have tried the solutions mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802189/psycopg2-single-quote-exception) like replacing a single quote with a double-quote and escaping the single quote but still have the issue.

Comment: Can you give examples of `name`, `row` and `update_string` ? Please have a look at [Passing parameters to SQL queries](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), which should solve all your issues.

Comment: yes,  name = "table_name", row = ['val1','val2'...'val50'], update_string basically added excludes statement for each row item.

Comment: One of the values in the row is basically the text which has single quotes..

Comment: You are mixing identifiers - table & column names - and values.  Identifiers have to be inserted using string formatting, but values should be inserted using parameter substitution.  I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68153087/5320906) yesterday which goes into a little more detail.  It's about sqlite rather than postgres, but the principles are the same.

Comment: Take a look at [Dynamic SQL](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html). In any case for text value with enclosed single quotes use double quotes to enclose the string e.g. "This text has 'single quotes'"

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I finally used the Dynamic SQL approach and was able to make it work.